# Google Forms: How to differentiate answers with same name?

Tags: google-forms

My grid-multiple-answers question was like,

```
       Very Good      .    .    .      Very Poor
```

Q1

Q2

Q3

-- So, each of 3 questions would have 5 choices(very Good/good/neutral/poor/very poor). However, because I stupidly marked three middle choices' name as '.', In result spreadsheet, every good/neutral/poor answer was recorded as '.'.

Is there any way I can assort these answers, or way I can track down what respondents' answers were? (Unfortunately, I cannot redo the survey.) Is there any raw data saved which I can access?

Thank you.

Comment: I experimented with setting up the questions as you had, and the middle questions will show the answer as being closest to the last answer no matter how the middle question is answered.  So, there is no way to determine what any of the 3 middle answers were.  You obviously know that it's not Very Good or Very Bad, but other than that, there is no way to know what the answer was if the person didn't answer Very Good or Very Bad.